# Inserindo um objeto JSON em um campo JSON no PostgreSQL com Python

Tags: python, json, postgresql

Bom dia pessoal,

Estou com o seguinte problema, fiz um crawler e ele recebe as informações, mas na hora de formatar ela em formato json e inserir no banco apresenta erro. Segue o Código:

```
     valor_coleta = "3,5%" 
     info_crawler = { "valor_coleta": valor_coleta}
     info_crawler_json = json.dumps(info_crawler)

     sql = """INSERT INTO crawler(info) VALUES(info_crawler_json);"""

     connection.run(sql)

     return True
```

Eis o erro:

```
ERROR - column "info_crawler_json" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO crawler(info) VALUES(info_crawler_json);
```

Alguma sugestão de como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Vc está passando somente uma string como parametro para a função `connection.run()` e não o valor de `info_crawler_json`.

Comment: Nesse trecho `sql = """INSERT INTO crawler(info) VALUES(info_crawler_json);"""` info_crawler_json é simplesmente um pedaço da string da variavel `sql`, acredito que você teria que vincular o valor da variável `info_crawler_json`com o `values`da sua query.

Answer (score 1):

Python é uma linguagem que não tem mágica na sintaxe - você crou uma string fixa ao escrever:

```
 sql = """INSERT INTO crawler(info) VALUES(info_crawler_json);"""
```

O que está dentro de `VALUES` aí não é o a variável `info_crawler_json` , e sim, simplesmetne o o texto  `"info_crawler_json"`  - se esse texto fosse uma variável dentro do postgresql, ele seria usado lá.

Mas para colocar o valor que está na variável do Python dentro da string, isso é feito com as f-strings (a partir do Python 3.6) - coloco o exemplo no final.
Na verdade, justamente esse ponto de se colocar valores de fontes diversas dentro de comandos do SQL é um dos mais populares etores de ataque a aqualquersoftware, pois é onde são possíveis os ataques de "SQL injection".

Por esse motivo, em Python, ao inserir dados em SQL (qualquer um - isso é padroizado na linguagem), não usamos as formas de interpolação de dados em strings disponíveis na linguagem em si, e sim, deixamos o driver de SQL criar a interporlação para nós. O código do driver checa os dados, e faz um "escape" básico de caractéres espciais como `'` e `;`, evitando quase todos as formas possíveis de SQL injection.

No caso do driver do Postgresql, devemos marcar os pontos onde vamos inserir dados do programa com `%s` (ou `%d` e `%f` para dados numéricos). O driver psycopg2 não sabe nada sobre JSON, caso contrário até poderia já fazer a conversão - por conta disso é necessário passar o JSON como string - e essa conversão você já está fazendo corretamente.

## resumindo

Troque estas linha no seu código:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO crawler (info) VALUES (%s)"""
connection.run(sql, (info_crawler_json,))
```

(note a vírgula extra depois do nome da variável - ela é necessária pra indicar que estamos passando uma tupla de um único elemento, e não uma expressão em parênteses).

Nada impede que você ponha tudo numa única linha:

```
connection.run("""INSERT INTO crawler (info) VALUES (%s)""", (json.dumps(info_crawler),)
```

---

Interpolação de texto em Python:

Nos casos em que o dado não vai ser inserido no banco, e sim exibido no terminal ou em um arquivo de texto, Python tem diversas formas de interpolar valores dentro de strings. A recomenda foi introduzida com Python 3.6, e funciona colocando-se o prefixo `f` nas strings, e então, nomes de variáveis e expressões de Python podem ser usadas dentro de `{ }` dentro da string:

```
print(f"Os dados lidos foram: { info_crawler } ")
```